# How to invoke a java method without knowing parameter types using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to execute this string in java using reflection

```
String methodCall = "com.mypackage.util.MathUtil.myFunction(4,\"abc\")";
```

This code does the job for me (after little string parsing)

```
Class.forName("com.mypackage.util.MathUtil").getDeclaredMethod("myFunction", int.class, String.class).invoke(null, 4, "abc");
```

The problem with the above solution is that i need to know the parameter types before invoking the method, and unfortunately i don't have them.

As a solution i can get all declared methods using `Class.forName("com.mypackage.util.MathUtil").getDeclaredMethods()` , iterate, match name and parameter count, and manually check types with some logic to identify the appropriate method.

Can java do this heavy lifting for me with something like this

```
Class.forName("com.mypackage.util.MathUtil").getDeclaredMethod("myFunction").invoke(null, 4, "abc");
```

This code should try to match the appropriate method and can throw NoSuchMethodException or Ambiguity error when 2 or more similar methods matched. Also feel free to suggest other ways to achieve this use case.

Comment: If you already have `4` and `"abc"`, surely `getClass()` gets their types?

Comment: As an aside, this is one of the great freedoms of working in a language like JavaScript

Comment: @ControlAltDel, it is a freedom, however, in JavaScript you can't actually know if your method is called with parameters that make sense, and not some random stuff, like `add(15, [])`.

Comment: If you want to recreate entirely the way Java does overload resolution however, then I suggest that you look for projects similar to [C#'s Roslyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roslyn_(compiler)), but for Java. This will allow you to, at runtime, ask the compiler questions such as "given these overloads, what does this call resolve to?"

Comment: Iterating over `getDeclaredMethods()` is actually your best bet - given that most reflective searches don't support shadowing, you will have to convert between primitive and wrapper types, as well as have to travese inheritance hierarchy for other arguments.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Ack bad input is definitely the user's fault, not my fault ;)

Comment: @ControlAltDel, still, language compiler is supposed to prevent such simple user faults as nonsensical API parameters, and so the better the static type system in language, the better the programming process.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov If you'll allow me, the issues that the compiler prevents aren't really the biggest ticket problems in programming these days. Take a look at HTML 5's `Content-Security-Policy` and the problems that can be knocked out with it. Yes, the program may not work, but at least it's not letting others hack/steal your data.

Comment: Take a look at `JDKProxy` : https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies. It will allows you to override the behavior of your method without taking care of your parameters.

Comment: @Sweeper Please note `4` and `"abc"` are comma separated strings from input.

Comment: If you don't care about the internal invocation details and just want to have the String evaluated, you could have a look at Beanshell or JSR233 in general. For Beanshell (https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell) you can create an instance of `Interpreter` and then invoke `eval(methodCall)` on it, returning an Object.

Comment: @Vivek “`4` and `"abc"` are comma separated strings from input” which you have to identify and parse anyway. Once you have done this, you know the types as Sweeper suggested.

Comment: @Holger parsing strings yields another string and after further identifying the number it can match to int.class or Integer.class or long and so on. Moreover this needs to be mapped with the available method definitions and find the right one to execute. As M.Prokhorov suggested inheritance hierarchy may be an additional burden. Looking for a solution to heavylift all these and beanshell could actually be a choice for such problems.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem of identifying the appropriate method with types was eliminated with the help of [BeanShell](https://github.com/beanshell/beanshell).

```
String methodCall = "com.mypackage.util.MathUtil.randomNumbers(4,\"abc\")";
Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
String result = i.eval(methodCall).toString();
```

The performance of this eval execution is actually pretty good (~10-20ms) and i'm using this solution on a standalone framework, so i need not worry much. This also gives me an additional benefit to allow a complete java snippet on the framework for customisation purposes.

Special Thanks to @jCoder for the solution.